# Reg_exp in stored procedure needs "into"

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I have this statement in an Oracle stored procedure

```
select regexp_substr('hello,world', '[^(,|;|\s|&)]+', 1, level)
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('hello,world', '[^(,|;|\s|&)]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

However, the compiler complains that I need a "into" clause.  I tried (and knew before I did) and it didn't work, because reg_exp is returning multiple values.

Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `cursors` for `multiple-row` returns :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
      v_abc  varchar2(1500); 
  begin
  for c in ( select regexp_substr('hello,world', '[^(,|;|\s|&)]+', 1, level) abc
               from dual
             connect by regexp_substr('hello,world', '[^(,|;|\s|&)]+', 1, level) is not null )
  loop
   v_abc := c.abc;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_abc);
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use collections to store multi-row results.

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm):

The following example demonstrates using the SELECT INTO statement to query entire rows into a PL/SQL collection of records:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE first_typ IS TABLE OF employees.first_name%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   TYPE last_typ IS TABLE OF employees.first_name%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   first_names first_typ;
   last_names last_typ;
   CURSOR c1 IS SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees;
   TYPE name_typ IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   all_names name_typ;
   TYPE emp_typ IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   all_employees emp_typ;
BEGIN
-- Query multiple columns from multiple rows, and store them in a collection
-- of records.
   SELECT first_name, last_name BULK COLLECT INTO all_names FROM EMPLOYEES;

-- Query multiple columns from multiple rows, and store them in separate
-- collections. (Generally less useful than a single collection of records.)
   SELECT first_name, last_name
      BULK COLLECT INTO first_names, last_names
      FROM EMPLOYEES;

-- Query an entire (small!) table and store the rows
-- in a collection of records. Now you can manipulate the data
-- in-memory without any more I/O.
   SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO all_employees FROM employees;
END;
/
```